# Patio Paint - SouthEast Texas

Tags: paint, patio

We live in South East Texas (*Houston*)and we have very high temperatures during summer here. We have had a patio constructed by an independent contractor. He  has finished the patio work but is not showing up for the paint work.

He used pressure treated lumber for columns/posts.

Roof type is Hip Roof with [OSB](https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-2-4-ft-x-8-ft-Oriented-Strand-Board-660663/100072564) sheeting  and shingles on top.

**Questions:**

1. What kind of paint should I use to protect it from weather, water and mainly from rotting over time.  (*I see lot of options in HomeDepot, such as [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/WoodRx-1-gal-Pine-Cone-Solid-Wood-Stain-and-Sealer-600751/205372423),  and i am not sure which one to choose*).
2. Couple of columns are in the ground, how do I protect them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to meet the usual definition of "patio" - perhaps a larger overall picture would help to figure out what you have - for the posts, if they are "ground contact rated" you don't need to do anything - that's why they are pressure treated in the first place. If they are not, nothing you can do now will really help. If the wood you need painted included pressure treated wood, it needs to dry before painting anyway.

Comment: Yeah, give it "a year an inch" to dry, so a 4x4 give it 2 years.

Comment: Is this how the under side of the roof will be left? OSB is not typically left exposed to the elements; it is not weatherproof and the texture is usually considered unattractive, even after painting. Usually it would be covered with more of a “finish” material like wood, vinyl, or other siding.